# is ie7 mode inside ie10 reliable?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, standards, mode

My site works well if i use IE7 standard mode emulation with IE10 but totally freaks out with native IE7, having totally messed css almost everywhere.

Can i force this **standard mode** on native IE7 or i must recheck all and manually try to fix it?

I already tried adding this tag on **meta**:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

and already tried to set **doctype** as

```
<!doctype html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

all without any success

**Edit**: Found one interesting thing:
IE7 totally mess up your site if the first line in html is a comment! IE7 emulator doesn't so in some case (like mine) we can have totally different results! Now native ie7 and ie7 emulator give the same (messed) output :)

Comment: With both meta and doctype (TWO DOCTYPES?) you're not targeting IE7. The problem is the IE7 emulation is an...emulation, it doesn't cover all **bugs** of IE7 but, more or less, only its _standard_ behavior. To summarize: **yes, a first check** can be done with **emulation** but then you have to use **real IE7 for your tests**. Don't be surprised about it, in many many many web-sites there is an **additional CSS** (or a replacement...) loaded with IE7 to fix its issues.

Comment: thank you, i think my only option is to enter the "ie7-pain" mode then!

Comment: HypeZ, so afraid! ;) IE7 has been (and it still is) a big pain for all of us...